# Should I delete a corrupt .pack file in the .git folder?

Tags: git

I am unable to push to my remote because of this error:

```
fatal: packed object {some hash} (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-{abc}.pack) is corrupt
remote: fatal: early EOF
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To {remote}
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '{remote}'
```

I tried to prune/repack and it did not fix the issue.

I am considering deleting the corrupt `.git/objects/pack/pack-{abc}.pack` file, and maybe also the `.git/objects/pack/pack-{abc}.idx` if needed.

Would this fix the issue?

Comment: It would certainly fix the problem of having a corrupt pack. It might introduce many *other* problems though (missing objects). In general, when this occurs with a Git repository, most people simply remove the entire repository and re-clone from a known good version. That works quite well if you have a known good and complete version, although one should still investigate to find out what led to the corrupted pack file.