# error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)

Tags: git

I did a bunch of file renames in my codebase and when I run `git status` or `git log`, I get the following

```
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: packed object 7c136b36a909c0b98a2692bfa05549d3272b3f15 (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-ef02e0f7372fc24112f73ab686ee98af900dcb43.pack) is corrupt
```

```
error: unknown object type 0 at offset 867983212 in .git/objects/pack/pack-ef02e0f7372fc24112f73ab686ee98af900dcb43.pack
fatal: packed object b7bd677eaeec12af4d1345e3562f4f42f5ea6782 (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-ef02e0f7372fc24112f73ab686ee98af900dcb43.pack) is corrupt
```

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: You have a corrupted repository (via corrupted files on your storage device). Git has detected the damage to the files and is now refusing to use them. The only real fix is to discard the damaged files (and perhaps the storage device, which is apparently defective, although perhaps the problem is not in the device itself). Typically that means cloning a known-good version of the repository. Note that except for an egregious bug in Git, which would probably have been caught long ago, Git can't *make* a corrupt repository, so it's almost always some other software or hardware.

Comment: Given that both objects are in the same pack file, it's probably just the one damaged file. What damaged that file is a bit of a mystery but [you have company](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72142121/1256452)!